# Google Chrome - Custom stylesheet in non-default profile

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have a second Chrome profile set up, in addition to Default, using --user-data-dir="..\User Data\Second Profile". I'd like to use the custom stylesheet I have in my default profile in the second profile.

In case it matters, I'm using Solarized from here: gist.github.com/anonymous/1258555. (Super User won't let me post more than 2 links since I don't have 10 reputation.)

I copied the User Stylesheets folder with the stylesheet in it from %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User Stylesheets to %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Second Profile\User Stylesheets, but that didn't work. Just in case it was some kind of weird bug with that particular profile, I created a new one and tried the same thing, which also didn't work.

I only found one person asking the same question, [in Google's product forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/Nwgl9WPYD3k/QpjCN1tiNz8J) and then [in a Google group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-apps/5JBYLM-A7kY), and the answer just says to create the User Stylesheets folder with Custom.css in it, which I'd already done.

What else can I try that might get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Check about:version for the Profile Path and put the User Stylesheets folder in the folder listed there rather than in the folder you've specified in --user-data-dir="some folder".

I tried a couple more things after writing up this question, and did finally get it to work. Oddly, it was [a post explaining how to find Chrome version info](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/h0lqvt8jzT8) that helped me. I wanted to include in my question which build I was using - couldn't remember if I switched it to dev on this computer or not - and the "about:version" page includes a full profile path.

The path it says is actually %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\Application\User Data\Second Profile\Default, rather than %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Second Profile, so I moved the User Stylesheets folder to there, and it finally worked. :)

Hopefully this will save someone else from wasting time trying to figure this out.